# Как в Tkinter сделать таблицу с меняющимися значениями?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Задача: сделать поле типа Text, но разделенное на два столбца. В левом- не меняющиеся значения, в правом- меняющиеся, построчно. Как это сделать без костылей и извращений? Пример:

```
1 столбец  | 2 столбец
Вася       |  21 год
Коля       |  33 года
Игорь      |  44 года
```

значения возраста будут постоянно меняться какой либо функцией, но они должны быть привязаны к конкретному человеку, и положение в таблице (Вася- первый, коля- второй итд) меняться не должно.

Comment: Кажется проблема в том, что вы путаете структуру данных (список из пар записей) и их отображение на экране (табличка со строками). Это две разных вещи. Храните и работайте с данными как с парами, а выводите их как текст.

Comment: как вариант, тогда как закрепить определенное положение определенной строке, если я их загружаю например из тхт, количество строк- всегда разное, а в tkinter насколько я знаю- нужно четко указывать номер строки в Text для отображения

Comment: @kromster сделал так: создал словарь, поместил туда все строки парами, сделал text.insert каждую с новой строки, но минус в том, что при каждом insert расположение имен меняется (так как из словаря они в рандомном порядке берутся). Как упорядочить? Чтобы Васе всегда принадлежала только 1я строка

Comment: все в общем сделаю через список (но это мне кажется костыль)

Comment: `collections.OrderedDict` вам в помощь

Comment: @babyborn я думаю(точно не знаю) тебе подойдет HList из модуля tkinter.tix а вот тебе ещё полезная ссылка http://grelay.blogspot.com/2013/02/tkinter.html